# How do I Summon meteors and fight Eater of Worlds when there is no corruption in my world?

Tags: terraria

I noticed in my Terraria world that I have absolutely no Corruption biomes. Nada. Nothing.  I was really hoping to get my hands on some meteorite but it seems to be a pipe dream in my current world. Are there alternative ways for me to summon a meteor? Can this be done in the Crimson Biomes?

This is pretty weird for me since this is a large map. One would expect multiple Corruption biomes. This world is 3 days old, so it was created after patch 1.2

See Screenshot
[image: Map layout]

Comment: Further question for those who know: Can you import a Corruption biome from another world in order to fight an Eater of Worlds if your world spawned with Crimson?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Crimson and corruption are mutually exclusive - only one can exist in a world without the player bringing in items from another world. Breaking [Demon Hearts](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Demon_Heart) in Crimson chasms will achieve a comparable effect (the boss is different, prizes are very similar, meteors do fall) to breaking shadow orbs in Corruption.

Comment: Great stuff! but seems my hope is still lost to get an early vilethorn

Comment: I believe there is a Crimson-equivalent actually.  Unconfirmed, but what I have heard is that there are basic equivalents that come out of the Demon Hearts.

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot fight the Eater of Worlds** if your world has no corruption. In that case, crimson has replaced corruption, and while it is very similar, it has its own boss that replaces the Eater of Worlds. There are still very similar rewards (a magic item, an accessory, a gun and a spear) from the Demon Hearts, which replace Shadow Orbs.

Breaking the Demon Hearts will still cause meteors to fall and enable the chance for the Eye of Cthulhu to spawn at night.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I decided to make a second world which I will travel between, just so I can get stuff from the corruption too

Answer (score 0):

You can't fight the eow when you have a crimson biome if you break 3 demon hearts you get the brain of Cthulhu. it sucks. i know but you have a 50% chance to get a corruption on a world. so try again if you want to.also you can get worm food from a world with corruption and give it to your character with the crimson biome or somthing like that. i think you can fight the eow in a crimson biome.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure, but I think since 1.2, there is no Corruption in new worlds and only in old ones.  I could be wrong, but I didn't find any Corruption, only Crimson, in any worlds in 1.2.

Comment: nope. made another world. there is still corruption :)